# Nilpotent ideals in a ring proof

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, nilpotence, nilpotent-groups

I am trying to understand a proof I am reading but it doesn’t make much sense to me.

If $R$ is a ring with $I$ a nilpotent left ideal then $I$ is contained in a nilpotent two-sided ideal.

The proof goes like this.

If $I^n=0$ then $$(IR)^n=(IR)(IR)…(IR)=I(RI)(RI)…(RI)I \subseteq I^n  (\ast) .$$
Apparently I need to use induction to show this. Firstly, I know that $IR$ is a two-sided ideal containing $I$. However I don’t get how $(\ast ) $ works. I get that $RI \subseteq I $ since $I$ is a left ideal in $R$ but then $(IR)^n=I(RI)^{n-1}R \subseteq I^nR $ using some inductive argument but I don’t get why then $I^n R \subseteq I^n $ since surely we would need $I^n $ to be a right ideal of $R$.

Comment: Yes, $I^n$ is definitely a right ideal of $R$, as $I^n=0$ by assumption. Thus, $I^nR=0$, and so you have shown $(IR)^n=0$.

Comment: Ah. I believe the inductive step was to show that $(IR)^m \subseteq I^m R $ rather than just $(IR)^m \subseteq I^m $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you are correct to be suspicious that there is a misprint, or perhaps we should say a misleadingprint.

$(IR)^n$ is certainly going to expand to something with an $R$ on the right.  We can say $(IR)^n=I(RI)^{n-1}R\subseteq II^{n-1}R=I^nR=\{0\}R=I^n$

If it were up to me I'd just reprint the tail end $\ldots (RI)I=I^{n}$ as $\ldots (RI)R\subseteq I^{n}R=\{0\}$